# osmar returning objects with no features- mapping with R

Tags: openstreetmap, r

```
> src <- osmsource_api()
> bb <- center_bbox(51.3528, -0.4468, 7000, 7000) 
> wb <- get_osm(bb, source = src)
> wb
osmar object
0 nodes, 0 ways, 0 relations
```

Trying to pull data from OSM API using osmar package- could anyone shine some light on why this captures nothing?

[osmar pdf](http://osmar.r-forge.r-project.org)

Answer (score 3):

No features at that location! center_bbox takes the arguments center_lon, center_lat, width, height - looks like you're requesting a box centred on 53.3528, -0.4468. That's off the coast of Mogadisho, all blue water, and no features, on OpenStreetMap:

[image]

Looking at 'bb':

```
      left     bottom      right        top 
51.3213580 -0.4784529 51.3842420 -0.4151471 
attr(,"class")
[1] "bbox"
```

The distance between left and right is 0.062884 degrees which isn't very wide - 0.063 * 110 km (approx. width of degree cell at equator) = 6.93 km, and it's not picking up any features.

However, reversing the lat/lon in your example gives different results - looks like it's near London, but throws an error:

```
bb <- center_bbox(-0.4468, 51.3528, 7000, 7000)
wb <- get_osm(bb, source = src)
Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'You requested too many nodes (limit is 50000). Either request a smaller area, or use planet.osm'
```

Trying a smaller area:

```
bb <- center_bbox(-0.4468, 51.3528, 700, 700)
wb <- get_osm(bb, source = src)
wb
osmar object
910 nodes, 14 ways, 2 relations 

plot(wb)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you thats a really great, comprehensive answer. Will keep those co-ords in mind when I am next looking for pirates.